# HTML layout renders differently on fiddle and on browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a small web page, the source code of which is available on [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/9sqbowds/2/). It uses a [jquery plugin](https://github.com/mridah/autocomplete-lite-img/blob/master/src/autocomplete-lite-img.js) which I made for autocomplete.

The plugin adds a new `div (.mridautocomplete-list)` after the initialized inputs, which contains the autocomplete list :

```
<input id="test1">
<div class="mridautocomplete-list" style="display: block; left: 8px; width: 169px; position: absolute; background-color: white; border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221); max-height: 150px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; font-family: Arial; font-size: 13.3333px; z-index: 8888;">
    <p class="mrid-autocomplete-item" style="margin: 0px; padding-left: 2px; text-align: left; font-size: 13.3333px; cursor: default; background-color: white;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="mridautocomplete-item-image" style="height: 11px; width: 11px;"><span style="color: #4682B4; font-weight: bold;">a</span>aa</p>
    <p class="mrid-autocomplete-item" style="margin: 0px; padding-left: 2px; text-align: left; font-size: 13.3333px; cursor: default; background-color: white;"><img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" class="mridautocomplete-item-image" style="height: 11px; width: 11px;">b<span style="color: #4682B4; font-weight: bold;">a</span>b</p>
</div>

<input class="test2">
<div class="mridautocomplete-list"></div>

<input class="test3">
<div class="mridautocomplete-list"></div>
```

**The problem is :**

This web page renders perfectly as expected on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9sqbowds/2/)

But when I run the same code on my browser ( without fiddle ), it doesn't get displayed properly, shifting all elements ( SHOWN IN SCREENSHOTS ATTACHED )

Can anyone explain what might be causing the problem ?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.test2` class is a width of `80%`.

The other inputs have a default width of 173px.

If you resize the fiddle window to a larger width, you will see the same issue.

To fix this you could add a `display: block` to your `.test2` class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..it works !! so `display: block` should be added to all inputs if they have dimensions in percentage ??

Comment: @mrid No. If you want the element to "clear" the rest of the screen, then you could use `display: block`.. You would also be able to just add a `<br />` to create a line-break.. :) It depends..

Comment: and you mean if i could append a `<br>` after the div as well, it would solve this problem ?

Comment: "clear" meaning "take of rest of the space to right".. I am not sure how `.mridautocomplete-list` is styled, but it might be possible.. There is no "correct" or single way to do what you are trying to accomplish..

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried the display CSS property? Setting the second input to "display: block" forces the 3rd input to the next line.

Another option is to place the autocomplete Javascript just before the closing body tag. This also worked for me in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.